# How do I skip the first couple column when using a SQL Loader?

Tags: sql, sql-loader

I am being given a .csv file that has 18 columns of useless data, then 10 columns of useful data and then another column of useless data. Is there anyway to just grab the 10 columns of useful data and just skip over the rest? I just want to start of reading the file at column 19 and finish at column 29.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `filler`:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE file.csv
INTO TABLE test_sqlldr
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
  col1 filler,
  col2 filler,
  ...
  col18 filler,
  col19,
  col20,
  ...
  col29
)
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm) you can find more information.

Comment: I have never used filler before but I thought that it just put a NULL instead of the data into the input table. Is that correct? So I would need 18 columns on my input table that I would just fill with NULLs. This was going to be my fall back but I was looking to not need to put these 18 columns on my input table at all. So I would SKIP 1-18 then col1-col10 would be filled with 19-29. Is this possible?

Comment: Just added the extra columns to my input table and used filler.

Answer (score 0):

And with MySQL it would be :

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE file.csv
INTO TABLE test_sqlldr
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
  @ignore,
  @ignore,
  ...
  @ignore,
  col19,
  col20,
  ...
  col29
)
```